# how to stretch a single wallpaper image across multiple monitors

Tags: display, activity-monitor, wallpaper

I would like to stretch the *same* image across multiple monitors.. how do i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your picture actually is the perfect example of why this is incredibly difficult to do automatically.

You have 3 totally different screens [& for this the actual distinction as to whether one is a Retina or not is moot]

Visually you have one small, one large & one in portrait.

Bear in mind this is *extremely* rough...

If you divide the picture into 3rds, one third to each screen, then you get this...

[image]

The left monitor has what was a 'tall' ⅓ now squished to fit the screen.
Same for the centre monitor.
The right monitor has it's ⅓ give or take, about right.

The alternatives would be to eliminate any portion that doesn't fit,

[image]

or shrink it & leave blank space around it.... (but I'm sure you get the idea by now ;)

Really, the only way to do this & have reasonable control over it is to do it manually, then set each portion to each screen.